# Using cache with OpenACC

Tags: cuda, fortran, gpu, openacc, gpu-shared-memory

I am trying to use `!$acc cache` for a specific loop inside a Laplace 2D solver. When I analyse the code with `-Mcuda=ptxinfo`, it shows no use of shared memory (`smem`) but the code runs slower than the base condition?!

Here is a part of the code:

```
  !$acc parallel loop reduction(max:error) num_gangs(n/THREADS) vector_length(THREADS)
  do j=2,m-1
    do i=2,n-1
      #ifdef SHARED
        !$acc cache(A(i-1:i+1,j),A(i,j-1:j+1))
      #endif
      Anew(i,j) = 0.25 * ( A(i+1,j) + A(i-1,j) + A(i,j-1) + A(i,j+1) )
      error = max( error, abs( Anew(i,j) - A(i,j) ) )
    end do
  end do
 !$acc end parallel
```

This is the output with using `!$acc cache`

```
ptxas info    : 0 bytes gmem
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function 'acc_lap2d_39_gpu' for 'sm_20'
ptxas info    : Function properties for acc_lap2d_39_gpu
    0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Used 28 registers, 96 bytes cmem[0]
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function 'acc_lap2d_39_gpu_red' for 'sm_20'
ptxas info    : Function properties for acc_lap2d_39_gpu_red
    0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Used 12 registers, 96 bytes cmem[0]
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function 'acc_lap2d_58_gpu' for 'sm_20'
ptxas info    : Function properties for acc_lap2d_58_gpu
    0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Used 20 registers, 64 bytes cmem[0]
ptxas info    : 0 bytes gmem
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function 'acc_lap2d_39_gpu' for 'sm_30'
ptxas info    : Function properties for acc_lap2d_39_gpu
    0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Used 37 registers, 384 bytes cmem[0]
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function 'acc_lap2d_39_gpu_red' for 'sm_30'
ptxas info    : Function properties for acc_lap2d_39_gpu_red
    0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Used 14 registers, 384 bytes cmem[0]
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function 'acc_lap2d_58_gpu' for 'sm_30'
ptxas info    : Function properties for acc_lap2d_58_gpu
    0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Used 20 registers, 352 bytes cmem[0]
ptxas info    : 0 bytes gmem
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function 'acc_lap2d_39_gpu' for 'sm_35'
ptxas info    : Function properties for acc_lap2d_39_gpu
    0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Used 38 registers, 384 bytes cmem[0]
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function 'acc_lap2d_39_gpu_red' for 'sm_35'
ptxas info    : Function properties for acc_lap2d_39_gpu_red
    0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Used 14 registers, 384 bytes cmem[0]
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function 'acc_lap2d_58_gpu' for 'sm_35'
ptxas info    : Function properties for acc_lap2d_58_gpu
    0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Used 39 registers, 352 bytes cmem[0]
ptxas info    : 0 bytes gmem
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function 'acc_lap2d_39_gpu' for 'sm_50'
ptxas info    : Function properties for acc_lap2d_39_gpu
    0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Used 37 registers, 384 bytes cmem[0]
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function 'acc_lap2d_39_gpu_red' for 'sm_50'
ptxas info    : Function properties for acc_lap2d_39_gpu_red
    0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Used 12 registers, 384 bytes cmem[0]
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function 'acc_lap2d_58_gpu' for 'sm_50'
ptxas info    : Function properties for acc_lap2d_58_gpu
    0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Used 30 registers, 352 bytes cmem[0]
```

This is the output without cache:

```
ptxas info    : 0 bytes gmem
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function 'acc_lap2d_39_gpu' for 'sm_20'
ptxas info    : Function properties for acc_lap2d_39_gpu
    0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Used 23 registers, 88 bytes cmem[0]
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function 'acc_lap2d_39_gpu_red' for 'sm_20'
ptxas info    : Function properties for acc_lap2d_39_gpu_red
    0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Used 12 registers, 88 bytes cmem[0]
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function 'acc_lap2d_58_gpu' for 'sm_20'
ptxas info    : Function properties for acc_lap2d_58_gpu
    0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Used 20 registers, 64 bytes cmem[0]
ptxas info    : 0 bytes gmem
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function 'acc_lap2d_39_gpu' for 'sm_30'
ptxas info    : Function properties for acc_lap2d_39_gpu
    0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Used 29 registers, 376 bytes cmem[0]
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function 'acc_lap2d_39_gpu_red' for 'sm_30'
ptxas info    : Function properties for acc_lap2d_39_gpu_red
    0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Used 14 registers, 376 bytes cmem[0]
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function 'acc_lap2d_58_gpu' for 'sm_30'
ptxas info    : Function properties for acc_lap2d_58_gpu
    0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Used 20 registers, 352 bytes cmem[0]
ptxas info    : 0 bytes gmem
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function 'acc_lap2d_39_gpu' for 'sm_35'
ptxas info    : Function properties for acc_lap2d_39_gpu
    0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Used 36 registers, 376 bytes cmem[0]
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function 'acc_lap2d_39_gpu_red' for 'sm_35'
ptxas info    : Function properties for acc_lap2d_39_gpu_red
    0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Used 14 registers, 376 bytes cmem[0]
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function 'acc_lap2d_58_gpu' for 'sm_35'
ptxas info    : Function properties for acc_lap2d_58_gpu
    0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Used 39 registers, 352 bytes cmem[0]
ptxas info    : 0 bytes gmem
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function 'acc_lap2d_39_gpu' for 'sm_50'
ptxas info    : Function properties for acc_lap2d_39_gpu
    0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Used 38 registers, 376 bytes cmem[0]
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function 'acc_lap2d_39_gpu_red' for 'sm_50'
ptxas info    : Function properties for acc_lap2d_39_gpu_red
    0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Used 12 registers, 376 bytes cmem[0]
ptxas info    : Compiling entry function 'acc_lap2d_58_gpu' for 'sm_50'
ptxas info    : Function properties for acc_lap2d_58_gpu
    0 bytes stack frame, 0 bytes spill stores, 0 bytes spill loads
ptxas info    : Used 30 registers, 352 bytes cmem[0]
```

Also it shows by `-Minfo=accel` that some amount of memory has been cached:

```
acc_lap2d:
     17, Generating copy(a(:4096,:4096))
         Generating create(anew(:4096,:4096))
     39, Accelerator kernel generated
         Generating Tesla code
         39, Max reduction generated for error
         40, !$acc loop gang(256) ! blockidx%x
         41, !$acc loop vector(16) ! threadidx%x
             Cached references to size [(x)x3] block of a
         Loop is parallelizable
     58, Accelerator kernel generated
         Generating Tesla code
         59, !$acc loop gang ! blockidx%x
         60, !$acc loop vector(128) ! threadidx%x
         Loop is parallelizable
```

I am wondering how to use the cache (shared memory in CUDA sense) efficiently in OpenACC?

Comment: which version of PGI tools are you using?

Answer (score 3):

The compiler should be flagging this as an error.  You can't have the same variable listed twice in the same cache directive.  Since I work for PGI, I've added a technical problem report (TPR#21898) requesting we detect this error.  Although not specifically illegal in the current OpenACC specification, we'll bring it up with the standards committee.  The problem being that the compiler wont be able to tell which of the two cached arrays to use in which case.

The fix would be to combine the two references:

```
!$acc cache(A(i-1:i+1,j-1:j+1))
```

Note that the PTX info wont show the shared memory usage since this only shows the fixed size shared memory.  We dynamically adjust the shared memory size when the CUDA kernel is launched. In looking through the generated CUDA C code (-ta=tesla:nollvm,keep), I see that the shared memory references are getting generated.

Also note that using shared memory does not guarantee better performance.  There is overhead in populating a shared array and the generated kernel will need to synchronize threads.  Unless there's a lot of reuse, "cache" may not be beneficial.

If the PGI compiler can determine that an array is "read-only", either via analysis or when declared with "INTENT(IN)", and we're targeting a device with compute capability 3.5 or greater, then we will try to use textured memory.  In this case, putting "A" in textured memory may be more beneficial.

Hope this helps,
Mat

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response Mat. It helped me a lot. So, since there is no syntax for explicitly control the shared memory in openacc (syncthreads(), etc), how I can figure out that the way of using !$acc cache will help? Can I find it through looking to .gpu file generated by "-ta=tesla:nollvm,keep" or I should do something else? Thank you very much

Comment: Moreover, in case of using texture memory, how I can put the array "A" to the texture memory in openacc?

Comment: Hi Behazd,I don't really have a stead-fast rule on how to determine if using "cache" helps or not.  Implementing "cache" turned out to be very difficult for the compiler.  While PGI has done much better with "cache" in our 15.x releases, we still have a few cases left that need improvement.  Hence you could have a valid use case but the compiler isn't optimizing it as well as it could.

Comment: Though when using "cache" make sure that there is a enough reuse and that the compiler is generating the cached references (seen in the PGI compiler feedback messages via -Minfo=accel)

Comment: As for texture memory, since this is a feature for a specific device, it wouldn't be part of the OpenACC standard.  Instead you need to rely on the compiler to take advantage of the feature.  PGI does, as well as Cray and Pathscale.  You just need to try and make it easier for the compiler to tell that the data is read-only.  For Fortran that means using "INTENT(IN)", and for C/C++ use the const and restrict keywords.

Comment: Just a naive question; is the cache here the shared memory (CUDA sense) or is L1? I actually had good experiences with shared memory of CUDA for getting higher performance and I just want to pursue it with OpenACC. Would you please help me what is the right way here?

Comment: The cache in this context would be shared memory but for other targets may be L1.  Think of cache as a hint to the compiler about data locality and reuse rather than how it's implemented for a particular target device.